# I need a SQL statement that returns the number rows in a table with a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, count

I'm sure this will equate down to the use of the COUNT statement but I'm not very good at SQL.

Here are my SQL Tables.

### Teams Table:

```
TeamId     TeamName           RosterSpots 
----------------------------------------------- 
1          Miami Heat         12 
2          New York Knicks    10
```

### Players Table:

```
PlayerId   PlayerName         TeamId 
------------------------------------ 
1          Dwyane Wade        1 
2          Chris Bosh         1 
3          LeBron James       1 
4          Amar'e Stoudemire  2
```

What is the SQL (Miscroft SQL Server 2008) that will return the number of Players on each team?

output

```
Team Name         PlayerCount
-----------------------------
Miami Heat        3
New York Knicks   1
```

I'd also like to return the RosterSpots and Team Id but really just the COUNT part above is what I'm puzzled with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT t.teamid,
          t.teamname,
          COALESCE(COUNT(p.playerid), 0) AS playercount,
          t.rosterspots
     FROM TEAMS t
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS p ON p.teamid = t.teamid
 GROUP BY t.teamid, t.teamname, t.rosterspots
```

Comment: the LEFT JOIN makes sure that you also get teams without any players

Comment: COALESCE?  Now thats new to me.  BRILLIANT!  Thanks a ton for such a complete answer.

Comment: More points available cause I did have to make this slightly more complicated...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545660/how-do-i-join-a-third-table-in-my-sql-statement-which-returns-a-count-without-los

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.TeamID, RosterSpots, TeamName, COALESCE(COUNT(p.PlayerID),0) 
FROM Teams t 
LEFT JOIN Players p on t.TeamID = p.TeamID
GROUP BY TeamName,t.TeamID, RosterSpots
```

Should do the trick, but feel free to rename the count column to something more friendly.

Modify to a `LEFT JOIN` to allow for teams with no players

Comment: Still need to convert the NULL value into a zero, but I voted for the JOIN cuz looking for zero players is an assumption

Comment: You gotta reference the table being left joined--`PLAYERS`--in the COUNT. Any column in it...