# How do I JOIN a third table in my SQL statement which returns a COUNT without losing the 0 count items?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

A continuation from this question [I need a SQL statement that returns the number rows in a table with a specific value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544748/i-need-a-sql-statement-that-returns-the-number-rows-in-a-table-with-a-specific-va)

We left off with a SQL statement as follows...

```
   SELECT t.teamid,
          t.teamname,
          COALESCE(COUNT(p.playerid), 0) AS playercount,
          t.rosterspots
     FROM TEAMS t
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS p ON p.teamid = t.teamid
 GROUP BY t.teamid, t.teamname, t.rosterspots
```

I have one more constraint to add.  WHAT IF, players need to pass a Medical Exam before they count towards the "playercount"?

I'll introduce the table.

```
MedicalTests
PlayerId  PassedMedical
1         1
2         0
3         1
4         1
```

Where "PassedMedical" is a bit (1 = true).

And also add 1 more ROW of data to the Teams table.

```
TeamId    Team Name
3         Toronto Rapters
```

This way I have a team with 0 players.

And the expected OUTPUT changes to:

```
Team Name         PlayerCount
Miami Heat        2
New York Knicks   1
Toronto Rapters   0
```

since one of the Miami Heat players has not yet passed the medical.

If I add

```
LEFT JOIN MEDICALTESTS m ON p.PlayerId = m.PlayerId
WHERE m.PassedMedical = 1
```

To the above statement I lose all the "0" rows?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Could you mention what was the output before adding the condition?

Comment: Miami Heat = 3, New York Knicks = 1.  I guess the data should be updated to show a team with 0.  So I'd say add 1 row to the TEAMS table (3, Toronto Rapters).  - ya for Canadian Content:)  The output would then have 1 extra line now for (Toronto Rapters = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood the question, but I don't see the need for the left join onto the players table. We only need the count of players. Why not something like:

```
SELECT t.teamid,
          t.teamname, 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players inner join medicaltests on players.playerid = medicaltests.playerid where players.teamid = t.teamid and medicaltests.passedmedical = 1) AS playercount,
          t.rosterspots
     FROM TEAMS t
 GROUP BY t.teamid, t.teamname, t.rosterspots
```

Comment: This assumes that all players have one medicaltest record. If they might have zero, I would still stick with the inner join since if they don't have a medical test yet, presumably they can't play. If each player can have more than one medicaltest record, another approach is required.

Comment: the information presented to us strongly hints that your approach is right.

Answer (score 2):

```
LEFT JOIN MEDICALTESTS m ON p.PlayerId = m.PlayerId
WHERE m.PassedMedical = 1
```

That's contradictory.  You are saying it is a left join, so the MEDICALTESTS record need not exist, but then saying the record must in fact exist and have a 1 as PassedMedical.  So your left join becomes an inner join in fact, and likewise, since you must have a MEDICALTESTS row, you must also have a PLAYERS row, so that also becomes an inner join.

Try this instead:

```
INNER JOIN MEDICALTESTS m ON p.PlayerId = m.PlayerId and m.PassedMedical = 1
```

Not sure how SQL server interprets FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar INNER JOIN baz...you want it to interpret that as FROM foo LEFT JOIN (bar INNER JOIN baz).
If that doesn't work, use a subselect instead; don't join, just add:

```
WHERE p.PlayerId IS NULL or (select PassedMedical from MEDICALTESTS m where m.PlayerId=p.PlayerID) = 1
```

Hope this helps despite my lack of familiarity with SQL Server.

Comment: While your result does return the correct count it fails to display the Teams that have 0 players in them.

Comment: @Justin: even my second suggestion?  Note that David's answer takes the subselect approach one better and should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing it as a computed column?

```
SELECT
    t.teamid, 
    t.teamname,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEDICALTESTS m WHERE p.PlayerId = m.PlayerId and m.PassedMedical = 1 ) AS PassedMedicalCount
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries are one of the worst techniques you can use for performance (they operate row-byrow not in sets), they should be avoided when there are other ways to acces the information.

Comment: HLGEM: without disputing what you are saying, in principle, the server should treat the above no different than a series of joins.  If there's a performance problem, I'd expect it to be only for certain versions of certain database servers, not across the board.

Comment: I didn't know that HLGEM. I almost always use correlated subqueries in preference to joins. I'll look into it.

Comment: In Transact-SQL, there is usually no performance difference between a statement that includes a subquery and a semantically equivalent version that does not. However, in some cases where existence must be checked, a join yields better performance.

Comment: Thanks Yves. I also can't see a way of avoiding using a correlated subquery to answer this question - a join would result in multiple rows being retrieved for each team if the team has > 1 players.

Answer (score 1):

Read this to understand the problem you are having:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Basically by putting the condition in the where clasue you are converting the left join to an inner join. Try this instead:

```
LEFT JOIN MEDICALTESTS m ON p.PlayerId = m.PlayerId 
and m.PassedMedical = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the link I now understand that part a bit more.  But all these answers still fail to return the rows where a Team has 0 players.

Comment: @Justin, please post the query as you have revised it, this should have fixed that.